# Mistake in book (probability of non occurence)

Tags: borel-cantelli-lemmas

Let the probability of success in the ith trial be $p_i$ and let $\sum_{i=0}^\infty p_i=\infty$ Show that the probability of having no success , $N$ is zero

N is a subset of the event that there are no successes in the first n
$$P(N)\le\prod_{i=1}^n(1-p_i)$$

Taking logs $$\begin{align} \log P(N)&\le\sum_{i=1}^n\log(1-p_i)\\ &\le \sum_{i=1}^n(-p_i) \tag{*} \end{align}$$

I believe that (*) is wrong. I took $n= 10$ and $p_i=0.5$. Can someone confirm. How would you prove it. I know that the first product tends to zero we can bound it by the maximum of the $(1-p_i)$ Would that be enough of a proof.

Comment: $\log(1+x) \le x$ is true for all x if you are using the natural log (i.e. $\ln$). See [this plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y%3Dlog(1%2Bx)+and+y%3Dx).

Comment: I'm using natural log. But it is not true for certain negative numbers. Try my example. It will say -3.0102999566<-5 which is wrong no?

Comment: $10\log_{10}(0.5) = -3.01029...$ is the base 10 log. The natural log gives $10\ln(0.5)=-6.9314...$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm

Comment: Ah I see my calculator and grapher misled me. Thanks.

Comment: `$\log$` comes out as $\log$ instead of $log$.  Similarly for sin, max, and lots of other standard functions.

Comment: I used log instead of ln in my calculation and graph.